# How to delete an object which contains a list of its bound methods

Tags: python, oop, garbage-collection

At this code, an object of `Foo()` class is still alive after creating new one. I guess that reason is in the circular references on appending object's list property. So, how to let garbage collector free old object, withot manual calling `gc.collect()`?

```
import gc

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = []
        print('CREATE', self)

    def some_func(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.functions.append(self.print_func)
        print(self.functions)

    def print_func(self):
        print('I\'m a test')

    def __del__(self):
        print('DELETE', self)


foo = Foo()
foo.some_func()
foo = Foo()

# gc.collect()

input = input()
```

`input()` at the end is just for keeping program running. Real project with this problem contains while loop, so  keeping old unused objects may cause a memory leak.
Now, output:

```
CREATE <__main__.Foo object at 0x000002747001D850>
[<bound method Foo.print_func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x000002747001D850>>, <bound method Foo.print_func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x000002747001D850>>, <bound method Foo.print_func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x000002747001D850>>]
CREATE <__main__.Foo object at 0x000002746FD0BB90>
```

Output with calling `gc.collect()`:

```
CREATE <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021E45F0D8E0>
[<bound method Foo.print_func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021E45F0D8E0>>, <bound method Foo.print_func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021E45F0D8E0>>, <bound method Foo.print_func of <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021E45F0D8E0>>]
CREATE <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021E45CDBB90>
DELETE <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021E45F0D8E0>
```

It's a result, that I want to get, but without using `gc`

Comment: can't you just delete the object manually like (del foo) ?

Comment: @parsariyahi `del` does not delete objects. Python is a memory managed language, it exposes no way to directly delete an object.

Comment: @parsariyahi it's have no effect. 'del()' removes only reference to object. It's still allocated in memory, and as I guess could be removed in future by garbage collector (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`weakref.WeakMethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakMethod) to avoid creating strong references to the `self.print_func` method in the list attribute.

Note that to call a weakly referenced method you would have to dereference it first by calling the weakref before calling the actual method:

```
from weakref import WeakMethod

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = []
        print('CREATE', self)

    def some_func(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.functions.append(WeakMethod(self.print_func))
        print(self.functions)

    def print_func(self):
        print('I\'m a test')

    def __del__(self):
        print('DELETE', self)


foo = Foo()
foo.some_func()
foo.functions[0]()()
foo = Foo()
input()
```

This outputs:

```
CREATE <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000018F0B397150>
[<weakref at 0x0000018F0B18E0A0; to 'Foo' at 0x0000018F0B397150>, <weakref at 0x0000018F0B18E1F0; to 'Foo' at 0x0000018F0B397150>, <weakref at 0x0000018F0B18E490; to 'Foo' at 0x0000018F0B397150>]
I'm a test
CREATE <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000018F0B397190>
DELETE <__main__.Foo object at 0x0000018F0B397150>
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/LightheartedTurquoiseChord